# Program to edit Localizable.strings file in Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, internationalization, translation, localizable.strings

Does anybody know a good program that makes translation of Localizable.strings file not such a pain on a Windows computer? There must be a tool that reads out the strings and displays them in a nicer way than a text editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for. Try messing a bit around with it. I suggest you use this to whether open it directly or just convert it to a readable format that you can use to edit it and viceversa. Here it is:

[Infekt](http://code.google.com/p/infekt/)

Comment: thanks, not quite what i was looking for.
i think i'll stick to a normal editor!